# WPF 3.5 SP1 V/s WPF 4.0

Tags: wpf

HI There,

i am starting to develop an WPF based application. so i was wondering if i should start with WPF 4.0 or stick to WPF 3.5 SP1. 
is there any significant changes WRT
controls,binding
performance ..etc.

Thanks for your comments and Recommendations
DEE

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: YES. Lots of.

Detailed answer: Go to 4.0 documentation - like all nice MS documentation there is a "What's new" section.

There is a LOT new for complex visualtizations - can make a hughperformance impact.

Comment: Thanks Tom for your reply , is learning curve big from 3.5 to 4.0